# Get value of selected radio button to Firebase

Tags: html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a form:

```
<form onsubmit="return send(this)">
<div>
    <input type="radio" id="1" name="check" value="check1" checked="checked">
    <input type="radio" id="2" name="check" value="check2">
    <input type="radio" id="3" name="check" value="check3">
  </div>
</form>
```

And js:

```
function send(formObj) {
  myFirebase.push({
     checked: formObj.check.value
  })
}
```

How do I get the checked input value and pass it into the object key `checked` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
var radiochecked = "";


for(i in formObj.check) {
  if(formObj.check[i].checked) {
    radiochecked = formObj.check[i].value;
  }
}

function send(formObj) {
  myFirebase.push({
  checked: radiochecked
}
```